# Finding out rotation number from slot machine symbols

Tags: permutations, combinations

Assume a slot machine has 3 reels.

The left reel has 7 pictures of the following numbers:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7

The middle reel has 5 pictures of the following numbers:

```
            3  
            4  
            5  
            6  
            7
```

The right reel has 3 pictures of the following numbers:

```
                       5  
                       6  
                       7
```

In each second all reels rotate only once in the same
direction and the slot machine is following a sequence like below:

### Slot Machine | Rotation No

```
 1  3  5               1
 2  4  6               2
 3  5  7               3
 4  6  5               4
 5  7  6               5
 6  3  7               6
 7  4  5               7
 1  5  6               8
 2  6  7               9
 3  7  5              10
 .  .  .               . 
 .  .  .               . 
 .  .  .               . 
 4  4  7              102
 5  5  5              103
 6  6  6              104
 7  7  7              105
```

We can see the slot machine sequence starts with 1 3 5 and ends with 7 7 7 and there are 3X5X7=105 permutations.

My question is, if we know the starting and end sequence, is it possible to find out the Rotation Number from a given sequence?

Or,

What should be the corresponding Rotation Number for the sequence
1 6 7?

I don't want to solve it by trial and error or by following a long sequence.

Comment: You can solve your problem with the chinese remainder theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem . Perhaps someone here will do that for you in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the rotation number of $167$ be $x$.  The first wheel starts at $1$ and repeats in cycles of $7$ rotations, so we have $$x\equiv1\pmod7\tag1$$
The second wheel is first at 6 on rotation $5$ and it cycles every $5$ rotations, so $$x\equiv4\pmod5\tag2$$
Similarly, $$x\equiv 3\pmod3\tag3$$

Since $7,5,\text{ and }3$ are pairwise relatively prime, The Chinese remainder theorem guarantees a unique solution modulo $7\cdot5\cdot3=105$.

Any solution to $(1)$ is of the form $x=7t+1$.  Substitute this into $(2)$ to get
$$\begin{align}
7t+1&\equiv4\pmod5\\
2t&\equiv3\pmod5\\
t&\equiv4\pmod5
\end{align}$$
That means that $t$ is of the form $5s+4$, so $x=7(5s+4)+1=35s+29$.  Now we substitute in $(3)$
$$\begin{align}
35s+29&\equiv3\pmod{3}\\
2s-1&\equiv0\pmod3\\
s&\equiv2\pmod3 
\end{align}$$
That is, $s=3r+2$, and $$x=105r+99$$

The rotation number is $99$.  You can check this by rotating $6$ times starting from $167$ to see if you end up at $777$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @saulspatz